Is Resistance to a trait applied once per hit, or once per damage type?
Warding Statuette gives "Resistance against ranged weapon attacks", rather than resistance to a damage type. If I take damage from a ranged weapon attack that deals multiple types of damage, will the warding statuette will reduce each damage type separately, like what happens with Resistance to All Damage?
Or alternatively, does it reduce the total damage, regardless of type?
For example, say I take the following damage from a ranged weapon attack, and have 5 Resistance to Ranged Weapon Attacks.

20 Piercing Damage
7 Fire Damage
3 Cold Damage

Will I take 15 Piercing and 2 Fire Damage?
Or will I take 25 total damage, with the resistance applied to the damage type(s) of my choice?

The rules say

It's possible to have resistance to all damage. When an effect deals damage of multiple types and you have resistance to all damage, apply the resistance to each type of damage separately. If an attack would deal 7 slashing damage and 4 fire damage, resistance 5 to all damage would reduce the slashing damage to 2 and negate the fire damage entirely.

I would rule that "Resistance against ranged weapon attacks" is a conditional resistance to all damage, so you would take 15 piercing and 2 fire damage.
